# Why is code not applied to each element with in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  
    var scrollwin = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 
  $('article').each( function(i) {

 var articleheight = $('article').outerHeight(true);

    if(scrollwin >= $(this).offset().top){
  
        if(scrollwin <= ($(this).offset().top + articleheight)){
        $('.progress').css('width', ((scrollwin - $(this).offset().top) / articleheight) * 100 + "%"  );
        }else{
            $('.progress').css('width',"100%");
        }
    }
        
    }); 
  });
```

```css
.progress {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}

body {
    height:4000px;   
}

article{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

h2 {
  text-style:bold;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress"></div>
    <header>Header content <br>
    header content<p>Header content<br>
    header content<p>Header content<br>
    header content<p></header>
    
    <article>
      <div class="article-1">
        <h1>Begin Article 1 </h1>
        <p>
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
          </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="article-2">
        <h1>Begin Article 2 </h1>
        <p>
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
          </p>
      </div>
      
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="article-3">
        <h1>Begin Article 3 </h1>
        <p>
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
        article content<br />article content<br />
          </P>
      </div>
    </article>
    <footer> <h1>Footer</h1>
    <div class="footer"> 
        <h4>Footer content</h4> 
        <h4>Footer content</h4>  
        <h4>Footer content</h4>  
        <h4>Footer content</h4> 
        <h4>Footer content</h4> 
      </div> </footer>
```

I want to have a progress bar generated for each article within a page, but
why is this code not working on each article element within the page... It works only for the first element but not the following ones, where the progress div is immediately 100%?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('article').each( function(i){

var scrollwin = $(window).scrollTop();
var articleheight = $('article').outerHeight(true);
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

if(scrollwin >= $('article').offset().top){

    if(scrollwin <= ($('article').offset().top + articleheight)){
    $('.progress').css('width', ((scrollwin - $('article').offset().top) /   articleheight) * 100 + "%"  );
    }else{
        $('.progress').css('width',"100%");
    }
}else{
    $('.progress').css('width',"0px");
}

}); 

});
```

The page has several articles within it.

Comment: Could you please add your HTML !

Comment: The reason why it only works on the last element is beacuse you do `$('.progress').css('width',"0px");` at the end of each loop for every article that is not being shown, meaning that even if article #1 set the `.progress` width correctly when viewed it will be reset to 0px when the `.each()`-loop processes the second article. That's why it only works on the last, because there is no more loop iterations to reset it to 0px.

Comment: Thanks, Removed the else statement from the snippet above to show it  working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize `$(this)` in your loop instead of `$('article')` -- I've made the replacements below:

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
  $('article').each( function(i) {

    var scrollwin = $(window).scrollTop();
    var articleheight = $('article').outerHeight(true);
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(scrollwin >= $(this).offset().top)
    {
      if(scrollwin <= ($(this).offset().top + articleheight)){
        $('.progress').css('width', ((scrollwin - $(this).offset().top) /   articleheight) * 100 + "%"  );
      }
      else {
        $('.progress').css('width',"100%");
      }
    }
    else {
      $('.progress').css('width',"0px");
    }

  }); 
});
```

In your code, you were using `$('article')` instead of `$(this)` which is only selecting the first `article` on the page. Using `this` will ensure that you're only referring to the `article` that is currently in the loop of `each`

Comment: Think I had tried that..., but with above the code it only works when I scroll to the last element (and I can see it makes all the other elements above work)

Comment: @Timbo I missed replacing one of the article references. I've edited it to reflect that. If nothing else, learn from my answer and write the code, don't just copy the code blindly

Comment: Also place `var scrollwin = $(window).scrollTop();` and `var windowWidth = $(window).width();` before `.each`.

Comment: Added a snippet to show that it only works on the last element